# SQL query summation

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**Unit**

```
Unit_id
Unit_name
Unit_cost
```

**Components**

```
Component_id
Component_name
Unit_id
```

They are linked together by `Unit_id`.

`Unit_id = 1` with name `Unit 1 Name` with a cost of 100 has a number of records in `Component`.

`Unit_id = 2` with name `Unit 2 Name` and a cost of 200 also has a number of records in `Component`.

So the total cost depends on the number of records in the `Component` table matched with the `unit_id` in the `Unit`, coupled with the `unit_price` in the `Unit` table.

I need the single `Unit_name` of the one unit in the `Unit` table that has the highest total cost (`Unit.Unit_cost`). Note I just need the `Unit_Name` only, not total cost.

Would it be best to use a `Top(1)` in the query? How would the query look?

Comment: Could you please add test data and explain how the total cost is calculated depending on count of related components?

Comment: You should identify which DBMS you're using; the answers can vary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select top (1) u.unit_name
from unit u join
     component c
     on c.unit_id = u.unit_id
group by u.unit_id, u.unit_name
order by sum(c.cost) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that unit cost should be multiplied by number of related components:

```
select top 1 name from(
select u.unit_name AS name, count(c.component_id) * u.unit_cost AS cost
from unit u join components c on u.unit_id = c.unit_id)
order by cost desc
```

In the inner query name and unit cost is calculated, at the outer query mname for unit that have max cost is selected. If cost should be calculated in some other way just change `count(c.component_id) * u.unit_cost` formula in the query